# How prove this sum $\sum\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}\dbinom{n}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^n$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

prove or disprove
$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^n=
(1-z)(-z)^k$$

my try: since
$$\binom{k}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^k+\binom{k+1}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^{k+1}+\binom{k+2}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^{k+2}+\cdots=\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^{k}\left[\binom{k}{k}+\binom{k+1}{k}\dfrac{-z}{1-z}+\binom{k+2}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^2+\cdots\right]
=\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^k\left[\binom{k}{0}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^0+\binom{k+1}{1}\dfrac{-z}{1-z}+\binom{k+2}{2}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^2+\cdots\right]
$$

Comment: This is the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for exponent $\alpha=-1$.

Comment: @Lucian It's $-(k+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^n=
(1-z)(-z)^k$$
\begin{align*}
&\binom{k}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^k+\binom{k+1}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^{k+1}+\binom{k+2}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^{k+2}+\cdots\\
&=\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^{k}\left[\binom{k}{k}+\binom{k+1}{k}\dfrac{-z}{1-z}+\binom{k+2}{k}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^2+\cdots\right]\\
&=\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^k\left[\binom{k}{0}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^0+\binom{k+1}{1}\dfrac{-z}{1-z}+\binom{k+2}{2}\left(\dfrac{-z}{1-z}\right)^2+\cdots\right]
\end{align*}
since
$$\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}=\binom{n}{n}+\binom{n+1}{n}x+\binom{n+2}{n}x^2+\binom{n+k}{n}x^k+\cdots$$
let$x=\dfrac{-z}{1-z}$